# How to work with C pipes on a Mac?

Tags: c, xcode

I'm experimenting with pipes in C. I want to connect the Standard Output of `file1`:

```
int main() {
    printf("6");
}
```

...to the Standard Input of `file2`:

```
int main() {
    int number;
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("The number is %d.", number);
}
```

The output should be: `The number is 6.` In Xcode, `file1` is appended to the executable (the target). I open the Terminal app, change the directory to the Debug folder (which contains the executable file) and issue this line:

```
.\TestDrive | /usr/someone/somewhere/file2.c
```

`TestDrive` is the name of the executable file (that contains `file1`). Since `file2` is not contained in the Debug folder, I have to specify the full path of it. If you wish, you can download the project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q1t789mw58jlig7/TestDrive.zip?dl=0).

In the console, I get `Permission denied`. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You can't execute C source code directly. (`/usr/someone/somewhere/file2.c`) You have to compile it first and run the resulting executable file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are piping into `/usr/someone/somewhere/file2.c`, it is expected that that file is executable; `.c` files generally are not, but the file that got generated by compiling it probably is.

Comment: Thank you so much! I added a new target to the Xcode project and now I'm good to go!

Answer (score -1):

You should make your TestDrive file executable, from the command line via chmod.